# Openstack database create instance BadRequestException

Tags: openstack, openstacksdk

I used `openstack sdk` for create new database instance, but it raise error **BadRequestException:**

```
BadRequestException: 400: Client Error for url: 
[URL]:8779/v1.0/ab77ed8ae3f744f4baf4fb7bc97848cc/instances,
Resource None cannot be found.
```

My data:

```
data: dict = {'name': 'nhinn-db-01',
 'nics': [{'net-id': 'd57e7864-5961-4a64-a5ce-005e05d71ccf'}],
 'datastore': {'type': 'mysql', 'version': '5.7.31'},
 'flavor': object Flavor
}
```

```
conn: Connection
conn.database.create_instance(**data)
```

Comment: What's the image ? And what's the process listening `8779` port?

Comment: @VictorLee that's create database instance, It dosen't need the image.